# Manage Cache content remotely via JCache

Tags: ehcache, jcache

I have a requirement where I want to view, modify the content of or add new entry  to the cache entries. I am using JCache API to and EHCache as the provider.

I don't want to write any wrapper API to expose the cache contents. I am wondering is there a way to access the cache contents remotely.
I see there are two MBeans supported by JCache but those are for Configuration & Statistics data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[JSR-107](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107) has no remoting API defined.
You will need to look at the provider specific APIs, Ehcache in your case.